# Sidekiq does not see changes in database table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

Versions:
ruby 2.5.5p157 (2019-03-15 revision 67260) [x86_64-linux]
Rails 5.1.7
sidekiq 6.0(Gem)

In my application I can add one string column and this column is added to a database table that is used to assign one paramter to existing table. I use ActiveRecord::Migration add_column to add the column.

The column is indeed added, but when I run the Sidekiq job, it complains about this new column missing:
ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'visma_id' for BookingItem.

Restarting Sidekiq doesn't help.

This doesn't happen in development, only in production.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, verify if you have properly migrated on production using

`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

If that does not work, I suspect sidekiq is not properly shutdown if this type of error is happening, you need to properly verify if sidekiq is not running, you can do it by

```
ps aux | grep sidekiq
```

and kill all related PIDs using `kill -9 listed ids` of the previous commands, also you can use `htop` command to see for how much time sidekiq is running in the listed processes.